# How to offset the content

Tags: html, css, offset

I have a fixed navigation which is covering my slider.
I need to offset whole content for about 100px but without navigation.

I hope You know what I mean.

Thanks a lot for Your help.

Edit//
This is my navigation. 
And this is a screen
http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2725-89.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="navbar-fixed-top" id="mainmenu">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="wrap">
                <div id="logo"><a href="#" title="name"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="name"></a></div>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#intro">Introduction<span></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#how">How it works<span></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#testimonials">Testimonials<span></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact<span></span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About Us<span></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                        <div class="moveDown">
                            <div class="anchor-inner">
                            <div class="anchor-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mobile-togglemenu">
                        <div class="anchor-inner">
                            <div class="anchor-arrow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please share a code snippet.

Comment: What have you tried? Give us some of your code, and what you would like to happen/what happens at the moment.

Comment: "I hope You know what I mean." Unfortunately we don't... most of us lost our clairvoyant abilities, so it would be really nice to **include some code and a functional, minimal snippet** to illustrate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that you want to move all the site 100px down except the navigation bar, is it correct?

If so, wrap all the content in a  tag and give it an offset with

```
.wrapper{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?